# Cloning item. The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to clone a model but when I try to I get the error in the title. This is what I'm doing

Button in vue.js

```
<a class="btn-link-clone action-button" :href="'survey/clone/'+scope.row.id">
    <i class="fas fa-clone col-margin"></i>
</a>
```

Route in web.php

```
Route::post('survey/clone/{id}', 'SurveyController@cloneSurvey');
```

CloneSurvey in SurveyController

```
public function cloneSurvey($id)
{
    $survey = Survey::findOrFail($id);
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $now = Carbon::now();
    $activePeriod = Period::whereDate('start_date', '<=', $now)
        ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $now)->get();
    $clone = new Survey();
    $clone->fill($survey->toArray());
    $clone->name .= ' Clonado';
    $clone->save();

    $eval = Evaluation::findOrFail($clone->id);
    if (empty($eval)) {
        $eval = new Evaluation();
    }
    $eval->survey_id = $clone->id;
    if (!empty($activePeriod)) {
        $eval->init_date = $activePeriod->start_date;
        $eval->end_date = $activePeriod->end_date;
    }
    $report = $activePeriod->end_date;
    $date = strtotime($report);
    $date = strtotime('+ 1 week', $date);
    $eval->report_date = $date;
    $eval->save();

    $questions = $survey->surveyQuestions()->get()->pluck('survey_question_id')->toArray();
    if (count($questions) > 0) {
        $clone->surveyQuestions()->sync($questions);
    }

    DB::commit();
    return back();
}
```

What is making this happen?

I've also tried this
button in vue.js

```
<div class="btn-link-clone action-button"
    @click="clone(scope.row)">
    <i class="fas fa-clone col-margin"></i>
</div>
```

method in vue.js

```
clone(row) {
    this.$http.post('survey/clone/' + row.id)
        .then(
            () => {
                this.surveys = this.$page.surveys;
         },
         (res) => {}
    )
},
```

with the route the same and I get a 419 (unknown status)

Comment: Clicking on an `<a>` tag will perform a `GET` request to the associated `href`. If you have a `POST` route, you need a `<form>` with `method="POST"`, and your `<a>` should be a `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit"/>` .

Comment: An `<a>` tag causes a GET request when clicked, not a POST.

If you want a POST, you need to `<form method="post">` or use JavaScript to initiate a POST request via AJAX.

Comment: A 419 error indicates CSRF issues. Read https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf.

Comment: @ceejayoz now I'm getting the 404 error again, with the same code in my edit

Comment: Then you need to debug it. Check `php artisan route:list`, check your network panel, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz it ended up being a error in the controller function code, in the findOrFail

Answer (score 2):

You need your `Route` to use the `get` method rather than the `post` method. Like so:

```
Route::get('survey/clone/{id}', 'SurveyController@cloneSurvey');
```

When a user clicks on a link, that is almost always a `GET` request.

**EDIT**:

Based on the comments, I agree that changes should not be done via a get request anyway. This example should be a `POST` request.

Your Vue component:

```
<template>

...

<form>
    <button 
        class="btn-link-clone action-button" 
        @click.prevent="submit(scope.row.id)"
    >
            <i class="fas fa-clone col-margin"></i>
    </button>
</form>

...

</template>

<script>
export default {

...

methods: {
    submit (id) {
        // use whatever http request library you choose to execute POST HTTP request.
    }
}

...


</script>
```

Alternatively, you could use `@submit.prevent` on the `form` tag instead of the `@click.prevent` on the `button`.

Then, as long as `scope.row.id` was defined on the frontend, you can use:

```
Route::post('survey/clone/{id}', 'SurveyController@cloneSurvey');
```

Comment: While this *will* work, the general rule is you shouldn't make *changes* via a GET request, as it can cause some fairly serious problems. For example, browsers may pre-load URLs if they think you'll click them, and search engines may access GET requests.

Comment: @Nancy - Try with my edit. This should work so long as `scope.row.id` is defined.

Comment: check my edit, I added something like this to the question

Comment: @Nancy - Just to be sure, you have `console.log`ed `row` in your `clone` method and it is defined? And two other things that might or might not help. Do you need to put a `/` in front of `survey/clone/` in your `$http.post` method? Also, you might need to `@click.prevent` instead of just `@click` on you `div` tag (should actually be a `button` tag IMO).

Answer (score 1):

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

You are making a `GET` request to a `Route` that only supports the `POST` method.

Either your vue app is making a ajax request to your server with missing headers or form incorrect form action.

You may also be passing something like a `GET` parameter as part of your request

i.e. `http://my-app/api/example?var1=asdasdasdas`